# COUNT(*) Maximum function nesting level

Tags: php, sql

When using count (*) php is returning the limit error reached. I have already changed my php.ini and set the value to 1000, but still continues to return error.

Count function

```
$this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM ". db_table_prefix ."users");
```

DATABASE FUNCTION

```
public function query($sql, $args = [])
{
        if (!$args)
            return $this->query($sql);

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);

        return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: How many rows are you expecting?

Comment: if you are selecting a huge amount of data, have you tried setting `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` to `FALSE`. Using: `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);` Some light reading  [how to execute unbuffered queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php)

Comment: I did not understand because "Maximum function nesting level" comes from PHP not SQL. Probably you are trying to reach nested references or function. The problem is in your code, if your sql query is wrong you get mysql exception, not this error.

Answer (score 0):

Once try this transaction method. Hope it helps

```
public function query($sql, $args = [])
{
    try{

       //We start our transaction.
       $pdo->beginTransaction();

        if (!$args)
            return $this->query($sql);

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
       $pdo->commit();
     }
     catch(Exception $e){    
       $pdo->rollBack();
     }




        return $stmt;
}
```